# Both training loss and validation loss are always zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I just started learning CNN and tensorflow recently. And I met one case when testing a fully convolution network (based on VGG16), in which I found that both training loss and validation loss are zero, and never changing. So the network can never learn any positive features. Hope anyone could tell me what is going on in my network.

[Accuracy and loss plotted in tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAgQG.png)

I implemented the network with the latest tflearn (grabbing from github directly). At conv5 layers, I used atrous_conv_2d, instead of conv_2d, and I merged the first four pooling layers and the last fully convolution layer, after upsampling them to the same scale (by using upscore_layer).

The code is shown as below. By the way, what I am doing is to implement the FCN proposed in this paper (http://i.cs.hku.hk/~gbli/deep_saliency.html), by using tflearn or tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected, activation
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d, atrous_conv_2d, upscore_layer
from tflearn.layers.merge_ops import merge
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization,batch_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.data_preprocessing import ImagePreprocessing
from tflearn.data_augmentation import ImageAugmentation

def InitMSFCN(t_xWSize,t_xHSize,t_channel=1,img_aug=None,img_prep=None, l_rate = 0.0002): 

    data = input_data(shape=[None, t_xHSize, t_xWSize, t_channel],
                    data_augmentation=img_aug,
                    data_preprocessing=img_prep)

    data_conv = conv_2d(data, 128, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name='data_conv')
    data_conv = dropout(data_conv, 0.5, name='drop_data_conv')
    data_fc = conv_2d(data_conv, 128, 1, strides=1, activation='relu', name='data_fc')
    data_fc = dropout(data_fc, 0.5, name='drop_data_fc')
    data_ms_silhouette = conv_2d(data_fc, 1, 1, name='data_ms_silhouette')

    conv1_1 = conv_2d(data, 64, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1')
    conv1_2 = conv_2d(conv1_1, 64, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2')
    pool1 = max_pool_2d(conv1_2, 3, strides=2, name='pool1')

    pool1_conv = conv_2d(pool1, 128, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool1_conv')
    pool1_conv = dropout(pool1_conv, 0.5, name='drop_pool1_conv')
    pool1_fc = conv_2d(pool1_conv, 128, 1, activation='relu', name='pool1_fc')
    pool1_fc = dropout(pool1_fc, 0.5, name='drop_pool1_fc')
    pool1_ms_silhouette = conv_2d(pool1_fc, 1, 1, name='pool1_ms_silhouette')

    conv2_1 = conv_2d(pool1, 128, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1')
    conv2_2 = conv_2d(conv2_1, 128, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2')
    pool2 = max_pool_2d(conv2_2, 3, strides=2, name='pool2')

    pool2_conv = conv_2d(pool2, 128, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool2_conv')
    pool2_conv = dropout(pool2_conv, 0.5, name='drop_pool2_conv')
    pool2_fc = conv_2d(pool2_conv, 128, 1, activation='relu', name='pool2_fc')
    pool2_fc = dropout(pool2_fc, 0.5, name='drop_pool2_fc')
    pool2_ms_silhouette = conv_2d(pool2_fc, 1, 1, name='pool2_ms_silhouette')

    conv3_1 = conv_2d(pool2, 256, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1')
    conv3_2 = conv_2d(conv3_1, 256, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2')
    conv3_3 = conv_2d(conv3_2, 256, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3')
    pool3 = max_pool_2d(conv3_3, 3, strides=2, name='pool3')

    pool3_conv = conv_2d(pool3, 128, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool3_conv')
    pool3_conv = dropout(pool3_conv, 0.5, name='drop_pool3_conv')
    pool3_fc = conv_2d(pool3_conv, 128, 1, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool3_fc')
    pool3_fc = dropout(pool3_fc, 0.5, name='drop_pool3_fc')
    pool3_ms_silhouette = conv_2d(pool3_fc, 1, 1, name='pool3_ms_silhouette')

    conv4_1 = conv_2d(pool3, 512, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1')
    conv4_2 = conv_2d(conv4_1, 512, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2')
    conv4_3 = conv_2d(conv4_2, 512, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3')
    pool4 = max_pool_2d(conv4_3, 3, strides=1, name='pool4')

    pool4_conv = conv_2d(pool4, 128, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool4_conv')
    pool4_conv = dropout(pool4_conv, 0.5, name='drop_pool4_conv')
    pool4_fc = conv_2d(pool4_conv, 128, 1, strides=1, activation='relu', name='pool4_fc')
    pool4_fc = dropout(pool4_fc, 0.5, name='drop_pool4_fc')
    pool4_ms_silhouette = conv_2d(pool4_fc, 1, 1, name='pool4_ms_silhouette')

    conv5_1 = atrous_conv_2d(pool4, 512, 3, rate=2, activation='relu', name='conv5_1')
    conv5_2 = atrous_conv_2d(conv5_1, 512, 3, rate=2, activation='relu', name='conv5_2')
    conv5_3 = atrous_conv_2d(conv5_2, 512, 3, rate=2, activation='relu', name='conv5_3')
    pool5 = max_pool_2d(conv5_3, 3, strides=1, name='pool5')

    fc6 = atrous_conv_2d(pool5, 4096, 4, rate=4, activation='relu', name='fc6')
    fc6 = dropout(fc6, 0.5, name='drop6')

    fc7 = conv_2d(fc6, 4096, 1, activation='relu', name='fc7')
    fc7 = dropout(fc7, 0.5, name='drop7')

    fc8_silhouette = conv_2d(fc7, 1, 1, name='fc7')

    pool1_interp = upscore_layer(pool1_ms_silhouette, 1, strides=2, shape=tf.shape(data_ms_silhouette))
    pool2_interp = upscore_layer(pool2_ms_silhouette, 1, strides=4, shape=tf.shape(data_ms_silhouette))
    pool3_interp = upscore_layer(pool3_ms_silhouette, 1, strides=8, shape=tf.shape(data_ms_silhouette))
    pool4_interp = upscore_layer(pool4_ms_silhouette, 1, strides=8, shape=tf.shape(data_ms_silhouette))
    fc8_interp = upscore_layer(fc8_silhouette, 1, strides=8, shape=tf.shape(data_ms_silhouette))

    fc_fusion = merge([data_ms_silhouette,pool1_interp,pool2_interp,pool3_interp,pool4_interp,fc8_interp], 'elemwise_sum', 0, name='fc_fusion')
    fc_silhouette_reg = activation(fc_fusion, activation='sigmoid', name='fc_silhouette_reg')

    network = regression(fc_silhouette_reg, optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 learning_rate=l_rate, name='fc_silhouette')

    return network

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # Real-time data preprocessing
    img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()

    network = InitMSFCN(104,136,3,img_prep=img_prep)
    model = tflearn.DNN(network,best_checkpoint_path='./bestCheck/',max_checkpoints=100,tensorboard_verbose=3)

    from glob import glob
    from os.path import join
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    imgs = []
    labels = []
    img_paths = glob(join('./ori','*.jpg'))
    for img_path in img_paths:
        name = img_path.split('/')[-1]
        print name
        label_path = join('./sil',name)
        img=cv2.imread(img_path)
        label = cv2.imread(label_path,0)
        imgs.append(img)
        labels.append(label)
    imgs = np.array(imgs).astype('float64')
    labels = np.array(labels)
    labels.shape=(labels.shape[0],labels.shape[1],labels.shape[2],1)
    print imgs.shape
    print labels.shape

    model.fit(X_inputs = imgs, Y_targets = labels, n_epoch=2000,snapshot_step=10000, batch_size=16, validation_set=0.2,
        snapshot_epoch=False, shuffle=True, show_metric=True, run_id='MSFCN')
```

Thank you in advance,

Zhe

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already added the code to my post.

Comment: And your training operation?

Comment: Attached my test code to the post.